# La conversión del tipo de datos char a datetime produjo un valor datetime fuera de intervalo

Tags: sql-server

Alguien me puede ayudar con el error `'La conversión del tipo de datos char a datetime produjo un valor datetime fuera de intervalo.'` cuando ejecuto un procedimiento de sql server, me pasa cuando le envio a la fecha un dia mayor a el número 14, pero si le mando un número menor a 12 no me sale error.

ej:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, FecRegiAnimal, CONVERT(DATETIME,@dFecNacimien, 103)) 
       FROM Animales WHERE IdAnimal = @cIdAnima
```

Pasa cada vez que utilizo el convert.

Comment: ¿Puede que estés utilizando  la fecha en un formato diferente a `30/12/2006`?, este es el formato correspondiente al estilo 103 (puedes encontrar [más información aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Comment: Buen día, ya leí la documentación que me colocaste y probé, y efectivamente el error es por el formato de la fecha que le envió, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.